# Where do I set ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades to false?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I have the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3036).

I get the error:

> An assembly with the same identity
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' has already been
>   imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

The problem seems to be an incompatibility between *Visual Studio 2013*, *Newtonsoft.Json* and *System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives*.

The suggested work around is to add

```
<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>
```

From looking around the web, it seems that this needs to go into the *.csproj* file, but I don't know exactly where to put it.  If I put it under the root node, I get an error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You can put the `<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>` tag at the top of the project file, in the first `<PropertyGroup>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{75678902-8224-4222-BB33-756784B2FA29}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>FooBar</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FooBar</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
    <ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**-- Edit : --**

`<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>` will save your day with Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, but it is not needed with 2017 : the projects will probably fail to compile. Don't forget to remove that item after upgrading to 2017.

Comment: This solved the error 'mutltiple assemblies' for me after referencing netstandard 2.0 nuget package with visual studio 2015.

Comment: This worked for me, but could you explain why it works?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by deleting the project and re-creating it (re-adding classes and re-importing NuGet packages).

I can only guess that, while updating the NuGet packages, something went wrong in the .csproj file.

A colleague of mine had a similar issue in Visual Studio 2015.  He resolved it by opening the solution in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I have same problem, however it works fine in vs 2015 but not when i trying to run the project in vs 2013.